# Encerrar script remoto como failure

Tags: powershell

Quero que o script remoto em determinada condição termine com erro e saia como failure.

```
if (($siteExists -eq $null) -and ($siteExistsInRecycleBin -eq $null)) {
write-output "info: Creating $($SiteCompleto)" 
New-SPOSite -Url $SiteCompleto -title $TituloFinal -Owner $Proprietario -StorageQuota '5' -NoWait -ResourceQuota '100' -Template 'STS#0'
}
elseif ($siteExists -eq $true){
write-output "info: $($SiteCompleto) already exists"
stop
}
else{
write-output "info: $($SiteCompleto) still exists in the recyclebin"
stop
```

Preciso que em caso do site de sharepoint já existir que o script seja parado e saia como se houvesse um erro de execução, algo semelhante ao kill -9 dos scripts de linux. estou executando esse script remotamente através de um orquestrador que só trata success ou failure.

Como o comando stop não existe, o efeito quando uso ele o resultado é o que eu quero, aborta o script com erro, mas na verdade o código está errado e não é nada elegante a solução

Comment: Bem vindo ao site. Pode editar a pergunta e explicar mais detalhadamente o que pretende fazer com este código?

Comment: Preciso que em caso do site de sharepoint já existir que o script seja parado e saia como se houvesse um erro de execução, algo semelhante ao kill -9 dos scripts de linux. estou executando esse script remotamente através de um orquestrador que só trata success ou failure

Comment: claudio, clique em EDITAR e adicione esta explicação na pergunta :)

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver usando o comando throw "mensagem de erro", esse comando envia tambem o returnCode=1 e interrompe a execução do script e o meu fluxo de orchestration recebe o returncode e trata como failure :)